# Pass or Post the input value without using form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working right now on how I can pass the value of `<input id="sub" name="sub">` that has a value of first 3 letters of dropdown option text. I need to pass or post the value of `<input id="sub" name="sub">` to process my query below.

When I choose for example the ITEquipment in dropdown, the `<input name="sub">` get the first 3 letters of dropdown option text. So now it has the value of ITE, that ITE what I need in my query. In query for example, $sub=$*POST["sub"] is equal to ITE so I used LIKE function, LIKE '$sub-*__' . Hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

How I can do that without using submit form?

Here's my example process of what I'm working http://jsfiddle.net/xqGLS/1/

Help please?

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $resultcode = $mysqli->query("SELECT category, id, maincode FROM category GROUP BY id ORDER BY maincode");
    $code = '';
     while($row = $resultcode->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $code .= '<option value = "'.$row['maincode'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }   
?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<br/>
Category
<select name="maincode" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onchange = "GetChangedValue(this);">
<option value=""></option>
<?php echo $code; ?>
</select>
</br>
Sub Code
<input type="" name="sub1code" id="sub1code" value="" readonly style="width:45px;text-transform:uppercase;">

<script>
$('[name="maincode"]').change(function() {
   $('[name="sub1code"]').val($(this).val());
   var input = $('[name="sub"],[name="sub1"]'),
    input1 = $('[name="sub"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="sub1"]'),
    input3 = $('[name="equal"]');
    input.change(function () {
    input3.val(input1.val() + input2.val());
});
});
</script>

<script>
function GetChangedValue(e) {
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
var elem = document.getElementById("sub"); elem.value = value.substring(0,3);
}
</script>

<input name="sub" id="sub" value="" style="width:35px;text-transform:uppercase;" readonly>
```

--My Query--

```
<input id="sub1" name="sub1" style="width:35px;text-transform:uppercase;" value='
<?php

$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code
WHERE sub1code LIKE 'SUP-___' ORDER BY sub1code");

while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $value = $row['sub1code'];
  }
  $first = substr($value, 0, 4);
  echo $first;
  $last = substr($value, -3);
  $i="0";
  while($i<=$last)
  {
  $i++;
  }
  $value2=strlen($i);
    echo $first;
    if($value2==1)
    {
    echo "00".$i;
    }
    elseif($value2==2)
    {
    echo "0".$i;
    }
    else
    {
    echo $i;
    }
?>'>
<input id="equal" name="equal" value="" style="width:60px;text-transform:uppercase;" type="hidden">
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Comment: "How I can do that without using submit form?" - What do you mean? You don't want the page to reload when you pick something from the dropdown? Or you just don't want a submit button but automatically submit by event change?

Comment: Jquery submit() on event?

Comment: I think you need to go through ajax (jquery) to submit form on change of event, without actually submitting it. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Craftein what I mean is. When I choose for example the ITEquipment in dropdown, the `<input name="sub">` get the first 3 letters. So now it has the value of ITE, that ITE what I need in my query. In query for example, $sub=$_POST["sub"] is equal to ITE so I used LIKE function, LIKE '$sub-___' . Hope you understand :/ pardon me

Answer (score 0):

**HEAVILY EDITED**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dd").change(function(){
        var v1 = $(this).val().substring(0,3);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url : 'call.php',
            data : {varReq:v1}
        }).done(function(returnResult){
            alert(returnResult);
        });
    });
});
```

call.php would contain your php/mysql script. To get the value passed through there should be via $_GET or $_POST. But you have to include the proper type in your jquery's ajax too.

So in my example, What I have on my php, just a dummy one.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['varReq']))
{ 
    if($_GET['varReq'] == 'ABC') echo "AAAA";
    else echo "BBBB";
}
?>
```

It pass this html element...

```
<h1>Example</h1><p>BBBB</p>
```

Then pop up message (alert) will be called showing the return value.

Comment: Ajax should do this. But that's the problem, I don't know how to use Ajax

Comment: what's inside of some.php?

Comment: Then you dont know how to use PHP either, maybe you should check some tutorials, before you post a question here...

Comment: There, soz about that.

Comment: yes. because if you have those current html elements, those as well they will be passed back as a result on your ajax. everything that you can view if you visit a .php on a web-browser, those are the ones that'll be passed back in ajax. was that clear? lol. you cannot pass value via return $result; in php. only when you echoed it out. So html elements outside php will be return, included in the result as well.

Comment: or what you can do, have an IF statement that IF $_GET or $_POST variable with certain name is present, process this and prevent the whole html from showing. via inside else {}.